# jQuery form validation fails to continue validating

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

What I'm doing is really simple. I just want a basic form, but if it goes to valid even once it hangs there and acts like the field is valid, even if it's not.

For example if I type in abc@abc.com for the e-mail address, and it checks out then it sets it as valid. But if I go back and put in an e-mail that exists, and should return false (and does) the status does not change. This also applies for the equalTo method.

It's really frusterating :/

Here's the JS [shortened names]:

```
$('#register').validate({
    rules: {
        scq: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: 'ajax.php',
                type: 'post',
                async: false,
                data: {
                    type: 'email',
                    email: function() {
                        return $('#email').val()
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        email2: {
            equalTo: '#email'
        },
        pass: {
            required: true
        },
        pass2: {
            equalTo: '#pass'
        }
    },
    success: function(label) {
        label.html('&nbsp;').addClass('success');
    }
});
```

The PHP for ajax.php:

```
if($row['id']) $success = true;
else $success = false;

echo json_encode($success);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...if I go back and put in an e-mail that exists, and should return
>   false (and does) the status does not change.

That's because you're manually adding a class called `.success` within the `success:` handler.  The problem is that nothing is removing that class if or when validation fails subsequently.

You could just let the plugin [automatically apply/remove the appropriate class for success](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate).  (It already does this for the error class.)  Add the `validClass:` handler...

```
$('#register').validate({
    validClass: 'success',
    rules: { // etc. etc.
```

And then remove `.addClass('success')` from your `success:` handler.

---

I'm not entirely sure where your `$success` variable fits in or if it's part of the problem.

However, [to simply test if validation has passed or failed](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid), you just check to see if `.valid()` is true or false...

```
if ($('#register').valid() == true) { alert('passed validation'); };

if ($('#register').valid() == false) { alert('failed validation'); };
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This worked btw, and I actually figured this out before I saw your comment. Upping this so people can see it in the future!